# Magento 2 - Add JS to specific admin page

Tags: magento2

My custom module can add JS to all admin pages, but I only want to add the JS to product pages I am editing.

I have my XML: view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
     <script src="module_namespace::js/priceChange.js"/>
   </head>
</page>
```

and my JS: view/adminhtml/web/js/priceChange.js

Wondering if I need to change the path, the XML or both?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change the name of the XML to catalog_product_edit.xml
This was figured out by checking out the vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/layout